# Quickly find recently changed files

Tags: python, linux

Given a timestamp and a directory path, what would be the quickest way to find (recursively) all files changed since that time? Running an external unix tool is fine.

EDIT : People, I'm not asking *how* to do that, I'm looking for the *quickest* way to do that in a *python* program!

My directory trees are quite large!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
import os
for root, dirs, files in os.walk('/root'):
    for basename in files:
        filename = os.path.join(root, basename)
        status = os.stat(filename)
        if status.st_mtime > timestamp:
            print filename
```

(Or something like that, haven't run it to test)

Answer (score 3):

Use the GNU `find` command with the [`-newermt {timestamp}`](http://www.gnu.org/software/findutils/manual/html_mono/find.html#Comparing-Timestamps) test expression.

For example

```
find . -type f -newermt "2012-01-01 00:00:00"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 touch -t 201201010000 REFERENCEFILE
 find /PATH -anewer REFERENCEFILE
```

Might work for you.

Comment: Probably you posted this *before* the question author clarified that he wanted to do it in python :-)